# Means of generating file hashes

Tags: c++, memory, hex

I'm working with a relatively well secured program. In addition to memory validation checks during run time, the actual file integrity is checked at start. Both checks are synced with the server and I've gotten past the run time.

I could just automatically write to the process once it's open, but just for fun I'd like to be able to actually hex edit the file. I'm not really sure where to start. I can provide that the program was written in C++ with a somewhat older version of Visual Studio. I'm sure many of the people on here have dealt with something similar, so could I have a general pointer as to where to start (e.g. how it's likely getting the data, if needed, or some windows function)?

Comment: You want to hex edit program on disk or in memory?

Comment: On disk - I've gotten by the process memory checks.

Comment: So why don't You use any hex editor and open\edit\save file in it?

Comment: That's the problem, it's detected.